# Attaching Refinery CMS to an existing Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

i'm trying to attach Refinery to an existing app and was wondering why it's not possible to define a "Refinery User model". Probably everybody uses an "User" model to deal with the application logic. it would be nice if i could define an "CmsUser/Admin" user to use with refinery.

or is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure from your question if you're aware of this or not, but Refinery uses [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication & authorization. Those docs might help.

You might also find http://refinerycms.com/guides/attaching-refinery-cms-as-part-of-a-larger-rails-devise-application helpful, as it does address integration of refinery and an existing app.

Comment: Page not found :( Plz help i am stuck on making the user model talk to the admin panel . Any help on this would be very much appreciated :)